# With files should I ignore in Oracle SOA Applications?

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-soa

Does someone know which files could I ignore when versioning Oracle SOA Aplications and Oracle SOA projects?

I usually ignore .data folder in my Oracle SOA aplications and deploy, SCA-INF and .design folders in my Oracle SOA projects.

.adf has some important configurations that I don´t know if is recriated. Can I ignore it too?

Is there any other folder to ignore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While versioning a SOA project, you can ignore the .designer, classes & SCA-INF folders.
You have to keep testsuites and other project specific files.

Comment: Hi @manisha-nagpal, sorry to ask you something several months after your answer, but on our project we embed Java "hand-written" code, that is stored in `SOA/SCA-INF/src`. So this folder has to be kept when versioning.  I am not sure of what to do... Perhaps this path is not the good location to store our sourcecode ? If it is the good location, may you update your answer in order to not ignore `SCA-INF/src` ?

Comment: Java embedding that you have added as "hand-written" code is not stored in SCA-INF folder. It gets coded in the `bpel` file itself. Whenever you build your SOA project, SCA-INF folder regenerates itself. You can go to the source of your bpel file to see your Java code. So, you may still ignore the specified folder.